# non-name on left side of :=

Tags: go, synchronization, channel

I am practicing / experimenting a bit with synchronisation mechanics in `go`.

Why does the last `for` iteration fail to assign the values held by the buffered channel `valchan` into `mysl` slice?

The error is

> ./myprog.go:28:7: non-name mysl[i] on left side of :=

```golang
package main

import (
    "sync"
)

const NUM_ROUTINES = 2

func sendValue(c chan string) {
    c <- "HelloWorld"
}

func main() {
    valchan := make(chan string, NUM_ROUTINES)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(NUM_ROUTINES)

    for i := 0; i < NUM_ROUTINES; i++ {
        go func() {
            sendValue(valchan)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()

    mysl := make([]string, 2, 2)
    for i := 0; i < NUM_ROUTINES; i++ {
        mysl[i] := <-valchan
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the "short variable declaration" syntax. From the [language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations):

> It is shorthand for a regular variable declaration with initializer expressions but no types
>
> ...
>
> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may redeclare
> variables provided they were originally declared earlier in the same block (or the parameter lists if the block is the function body) with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank variables is new.

Put differently: your code tries redeclaring `mysl[i]`. This does not conform to the "at least one of the non-blank variables is new" rule, so the compiler complains. Instead, you'll want to do only an assignment - using the `=` operator.

Comment: A bit of nitpicking: technically speaking, `mysl[i]` could not be a variable even in an otherwise correct context: `mysl` is a (compound) variable but `mysl[i]` merely refers to an element of it.